# How to make a conditional variable based on multiple variables?

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

Trying to make a catch all variable - so if a respondent answers "yes" to at least one of the 9 yes/no variables, then they will be placed into the "yes" category in the overall variable.

I've done this by:

```
overallvariable <- ifelse(df$v1 == "yes" | df$v2 == "yes" | df$v3 == "yes" | df$v4 == "yes" |df$v5 == "yes" | df$v6 == "yes" | df$v7 == "yes" | df$v8 == "yes" | df$v9 == "yes", "yes", "no")
```

However the `table(overallvariable)` comes up with:

| no |
| --- |
| ## |

instead of

| yes | no |
| --- | --- |
| ### | ## |

Thank you for your help!

Note: everything seems to work until I add v9
Note: Just played around with where v9 goes in, it doesn't seem to be a problem attached to the variable as it produces the output I needed. So it seems to be an issue with adding a ninth condition.

Comment: Please provide parts of your data with `dput(head(yourdata))`.

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to R, what do you mean by this?

Comment: You have the best chance of getting an answer if you provide a minimal example. You can paste part of your data into the question: `dput(head(df))`. Then people can easily use your data to get to the answer.

Comment: See [how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). How is `v9` different from the others?

Comment: Unfortunately the data I'm using is bound by ethics and protocols that do not allow me to share :/

Comment: V9 is very similar to the rest (most similar to V8) just a change in gender really e.g. Have you experienced X by female vs Have you experienced X by male

Comment: Let me explain: You don't need to share your actual data. What you need to do is to provide an example with data that reproduces your error. People can help, as long as they can reproduce the error. But for now, we don't know what the data looks like.

Comment: Note: Just played around with where v9 goes in, it doesn't seem to be a problem attached to the variable as it produces the output i needed. So it seems to be an issue with adding a ninth condition.

Comment: Well, this doesn't make any sense in terms of the code. This makes it even clearer that data is needed to reproduce the error. Like the question stands now, I can only offer, that you check if v9 is `character` and to check if there are no spelling mistakes or `NA`s in v9.

Comment: I think the NA's are the problem! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

here is a `data.table` approach, and also an instriction how to create some sample data ;-)

**sample data**

```
set.seed(123)
mydata <- data.frame(id = 1:15,
                     v1 = sample(c("yes", "no"), 15, replace = TRUE),
                     v2 = sample(c("yes", "no"), 15, replace = TRUE),
                     v3 = sample(c("yes", "no"), 15, replace = TRUE),
                     v4 = sample(c("yes", "no"), 15, replace = TRUE))
```

**code**

```
library(data.table)
# convert to data.table formast
setDT(mydata)
# columns to look in
cols <- grep("v[1-4]", names(mydata), value = TRUE)
# initialise overallvariable to "no"
mydata[, overallvariable := "no"]
# if 1 or more columns in cols have the value "yes", set overallvariable to "yes"
mydata[ rowSums(mydata[, ..cols] == "yes", na.rm = TRUE) >= 1, 
        overallvariable := "yes"]
```

**output**

```
# id  v1  v2  v3  v4 overallvariable
# 1:  1 yes yes yes yes             yes
# 2:  2 yes  no  no yes             yes
# 3:  3 yes yes yes  no             yes
# 4:  4  no yes  no yes             yes
# 5:  5 yes yes  no yes             yes
# 6:  6  no yes yes  no             yes
# 7:  7  no  no yes yes             yes
# 8:  8  no yes yes yes             yes
# 9:  9 yes yes yes yes             yes
#10: 10 yes yes  no yes             yes
#11: 11  no yes yes  no             yes
#12: 12  no  no  no  no              no
#13: 13  no  no  no yes             yes
#14: 14 yes yes yes  no             yes
#15: 15  no  no yes yes             yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R:

```
df$overallvariable <- c('no','yes')[1 + (rowSums(df == "yes") > 0)]
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", 
"no", "no", "no"), V2 = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", 
"yes", "no", "yes", "yes"), V3 = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "no", 
"no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes"), V4 = c("no", "no", "no", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no"), V5 = c("yes", "yes", 
"yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes"), V6 = c("no", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no"), V7 = c("no", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no"), V8 = c("yes", 
"yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes"), V9 = c("no", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no"), V10 = c("no", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

The dplyr package has the perfect function for the desired transformation: `if_any`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(overallvariable = if_any(V1:V10, ~ .x=='yes') %>% ifelse('yes', 'no'))
```

We can also use `purrr::reduce`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(overallvariable = reduce(across(V1:V10, ~.x=='yes'), `|`) %>% ifelse('yes', 'no'))
```

**output** using the data from @TarJae:

```
   V1  V2  V3 V4  V5 V6 V7  V8 V9 V10 overallvariable
1  no yes yes no yes no no yes no  no             yes
2  no yes yes no yes no no yes no  no             yes
3  no yes yes no yes no no yes no  no             yes
4  no  no  no no  no no no  no no  no              no
5  no  no  no no  no no no  no no  no              no
6  no  no  no no  no no no  no no  no              no
7  no yes yes no yes no no yes no  no             yes
8  no  no  no no  no no no  no no  no              no
9  no yes yes no yes no no yes no  no             yes
10 no yes yes no yes no no yes no  no             yes
```